# Не правильно выводятся элементы карусели

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, карусель

Всем привет! Есть адаптивная owl-carusel, настраиваемая через visual composer в wordpress. В параметрах отображения указываю выводить 4 слайдера, но выводятся почему-то 3. В чем дело? может быть где-то используется переопределение? Как можно поправить?

```html
<div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid top-products">
  <div class="vc_col-sm-12 wpb_column vc_column_container ">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
      <div data-columns="4" data-sidebar="no_sidebar" class="products-container   product-carousel view-grid">
        <div class="product-holder">
          <h2 class="product-title">ТОП ЗАКАЗОВ</h2> 
        </div>
        <!--/ .product-holder-->
        <div class="wrap-product-container">
          <ul class="products clearfix owl-carousel owl-tm-theme" style="opacity: 1; display: block;">
            <div class="owl-wrapper-outer autoHeight" style="height: 437px;">
              <div class="owl-wrapper" style="width: 3040px; left: 0px; display: block; -webkit-transition: all 0ms ease; transition: all 0ms ease;">
                <div class="owl-item" style="width: 380px;">
                  <li class="first post-3227 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail product_cat-meet product_cat-top meet top  sale shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple product-cat-meet product-cat-top instock">
                    <div class="product-frame ">...</div>
                    <--product-frame-->
                  </li>
                </div>
                <div class="owl-item" style="width: 380px;">
                  <li class="post-3226 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail product_cat-fish product_cat-top fish top  shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple product-cat-fish product-cat-top instock">
                    <div class="product-frame ">...</div>
                    <!--/ .product-frame-->
                  </li>
                </div>
                <div class="owl-item" style="width: 380px;">
                  <li class="last post-3225 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail product_cat-vegetarian product_cat-picca product_cat-top vegetarian picca top  shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple product-cat-vegetarian product-cat-picca product-cat-top instock">
                    <div class="product-frame ">...
                    </div>
                    <!--/ .product-frame-->
                  </li>
                </div>
                <div class="owl-item" style="width: 380px;">
                  <li class="first post-3220 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail product_cat-meet product_cat-top meet top  shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple product-cat-meet product-cat-top instock">
                    <div class="product-frame ">...</div>
                    <!--/ .product-frame-->
                  </li>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="owl-controls clickable" style="display: block;">
              <div class="owl-buttons">
                <div class="owl-prev">prev</div>
                <div class="owl-next">next</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/ .products-container-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

JS file

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $(".owl-demo").owlCarousel({

        items : 4,
        itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
        itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]

   });

});
```

Comment: каруселей 2 штуки на странице по сути одинаковых. пока решил стилями, но если есть более "правильный" способ- буду этому рад

Comment: А если каждой свой id + необходимый скрипт.

Comment: а как это сделать? назначение стилей внутри visual composer не воспринимает..